# ohlc(open,high, low and close) record between two date range on different time internal(1,5,15,60,120) minute, 1 day even there are no record

Tags: mysql, sql, stock-data

**What I have**

**1. MY Domain "User_Order"**

```
CREATE TABLE `user_order` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `fees` decimal(19,2) NOT NULL,
  `instrument` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `is_limit_order` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `market_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `order_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `order_status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `order_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(20,8) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` decimal(20,8) NOT NULL,
  `remaining_quantity` decimal(20,8) NOT NULL,
  `updated_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_t5ah1x4wm9314qclf90dy0lyu` (`order_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**2. we have following record in my table.**

```
| id | created_date        | fees   | instrument | is_limit_order | market_id | order_id         | order_status | order_type | price       | quantity   | remaining_quantity | updated_date        | user_id |
+----+---------------------+--------+------------+----------------+-----------+------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------+
|  1 | 2017-09-15 05:08:57 | 0.0100 | INBTCINR   |               |         1 | 12:05:52-0000001 | EXECUTED     | BUY        | 10.00000000 | 2.00000000 |         0.00000000 | 2017-09-15 05:08:57 |       3 |
|  2 | 2017-09-15 05:09:34 | 0.0100 | INBTCINR   |               |         1 | 12:25:43-0000001 | EXECUTED     | SELL       | 10.00000000 | 2.00000000 |         0.00000000 | 2017-09-15 05:09:34 |       4 |
|  3 | 2017-09-15 05:11:18 | 0.0100 | INBTCINR   |               |         1 | 12:05:52-0000002 | CANCELLED    | BUY        |  2.00000000 | 1.00000000 |         1.00000000 | 2017-09-15 05:11:18 |       3 |
|  4 | 2017-09-15 05:12:43 | 0.0100 | INBTCINR   |               |         1 | 12:05:52-0000003 | EXECUTED     | BUY        |  4.00000000 | 2.00000000 |         0.00000000 | 2017-09-15 05:12:43 |       3 |
|  5 | 2017-09-15 05:23:10 | 0.0100 | INBTCINR   |               |         1 | 12:25:43-0000002 | EXECUTED     | SELL       |  4.00000000 | 2.00000000 |         0.00000000 | 2017-09-15 05:23:10 |       4 |
|  6 | 2017-09-15 08:34:17 | 0.0100 | INBTCINR   |               |         1 | 12:25:43-0000003 | OPEN         | BUY        |  2.00000000 | 1.00000000 |         1.00000000 | 2017-09-15 08:34:17 |       4 |
|  7 | 2017-09-15 08:36:32 | 0.0100 | INBTCINR   |               |         1 | 12:05:52-0000004 | CANCELLED    | SELL       |  1.00000000 | 2.00000000 |         2.00000000 | 2017-09-15 08:36:32 |       3 |
|  8 | 2017-09-15 09:24:22 | 0.0100 | INBTCINR   |               |         1 | 12:25:43-0000004 | OPEN         | BUY        |  2.00000000 | 1.00000000 |         1.00000000 | 2017-09-15 09:24:22 |       4 |
|  9 | 2017-09-15 09:30:19 | 0.0100 | INBTCINR   |               |         1 | 12:25:43-0000005 | OPEN         | BUY        |  1.00000000 | 2.00000000 |         2.00000000 | 2017-09-15 09:30:19 |       4 |
| 10 | 2017-09-15 09:32:10 | 0.0100 | INBTCINR   |               |         1 | 12:05:52-0000005 | CANCELLED    | SELL       |  1.00000000 | 2.00000000 |         2.00000000 | 2017-09-15 09:32:10 |       3 |
| 11 | 2017-09-15 10:02:57 | 0.0100 | INBTCINR   |               |         1 | 12:05:52-0000006 | OPEN         | SELL       |  2.00000000 | 4.00000000 |         4.00000000 | 2017-09-15 10:02:57 |       3 |
| 12 | 2017-09-15 10:16:19 | 0.0100 | INBTCINR   |               |         1 | 12:25:43-0000006 | OPEN         | BUY        |  4.00000000 | 2.00000000 |         2.00000000 | 2017-09-15 10:16:19 |       4 |
```

**3. I am writing below query for every 5(300 in second) minute interval record.**
start date    = '2017-09-11 00:00:00' 
end date      = '2017-09-15 23:59:59'

```
select  FROM_UNIXTIME(floor(min(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_date))/300)*300)
                 as timestampDate,
        sum(quantity) as volume,sum(price*quantity)/sum(quantity) as wavg_price,
        substring_index(min(concat('created_date','_',price)),
                '_',-1) as open,
        max(price) as high,
        min(price) as low,
        substring_index(max(concat ('created_date','_',price)),
                '_',-1) as 'close'
    from  user_order
    where  created_date between '2017-09-11 00:00:00' AND '2017-09-15 23:59:59'
    group by  floor(unix_timestamp(created_date)/300)
    order by  created_date;
```

result for above query:-

```
 timestampDate       | volume     | wavg_price              | open        | high        | low         | close       |
+---------------------+------------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2017-09-15 05:05:00 | 4.00000000 | 10.00000000000000000000 | 10.00000000 | 10.00000000 | 10.00000000 | 10.00000000 |
| 2017-09-15 05:10:00 | 3.00000000 |  3.33333333333333333333 | 2.00000000  |  4.00000000 |  2.00000000 | 4.00000000  |
| 2017-09-15 05:20:00 | 2.00000000 |  4.00000000000000000000 | 4.00000000  |  4.00000000 |  4.00000000 | 4.00000000  |
| 2017-09-15 08:30:00 | 1.00000000 |  2.00000000000000000000 | 2.00000000  |  2.00000000 |  2.00000000 | 2.00000000  |
| 2017-09-15 08:35:00 | 2.00000000 |  1.00000000000000000000 | 1.00000000  |  1.00000000 |  1.00000000 | 1.00000000  |
| 2017-09-15 09:20:00 | 1.00000000 |  2.00000000000000000000 | 2.00000000  |  2.00000000 |  2.00000000 | 2.00000000  |
| 2017-09-15 09:30:00 | 4.00000000 |  1.00000000000000000000 | 1.00000000  |  1.00000000 |  1.00000000 | 1.00000000  |
| 2017-09-15 10:00:00 | 4.00000000 |  2.00000000000000000000 | 2.00000000  |  2.00000000 |  2.00000000 | 2.00000000  |
| 2017-09-15 10:15:00 | 2.00000000 |  4.00000000000000000000 | 4.00000000  |  4.00000000 |  4.00000000 | 4.00000000  |
+---------------------+------------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

**4. Above result give only table persent record even i need all record with default value or pervious record value ( open, close, high, low and their timestamp) for every interval**

expected output :-
date range= '2017-09-11 00:00:00'  and '2017-09-15 23:59:59'

```
 timestampDate       | volume     | wavg_price              | open        | high        | low         | close       |
+---------------------+------------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2017-09-11 00:05:00 | 4.00000000 | 10.00000000000000000000 | 10.00000000 | 10.00000000 | 10.00000000 | 10.00000000 |
| 2017-09-11 00:10:00 | 3.00000000 |  3.33333333333333333333 | 2.00000000  |  4.00000000 |  2.00000000 | 4.00000000  |
| 2017-09-11 00:15:00 | 2.00000000 |  4.00000000000000000000 | 4.00000000  |  4.00000000 |  4.00000000 | 4.00000000  |
................................................
.................................................
.................................................
| 2017-09-15 23:05:00 | 1.00000000 |  2.00000000000000000000 | 2.00000000  |  2.00000000 |  2.00000000 | 2.00000000  |
| 2017-09-15 23:10:00 | 1.00000000 |  2.00000000000000000000 | 2.00000000  |  2.00000000 |  2.00000000 | 2.00000000  |
..........................................................
..........................................................
..........................................................

| 2017-09-15 23:50:00 | 1.00000000 |  2.00000000000000000000 | 2.00000000  |  2.00000000 |  2.00000000 | 2.00000000  |
| 2017-09-15 23:55:00 | 1.00000000 |  2.00000000000000000000 | 2.00000000  |  2.00000000 |  2.00000000 | 2.00000000  |
```

**What i want**

1. output give only table persent record even i need all record with default value or pervious record value ( open, close, high, low and their timestamp) for every interval
   **case a)**
   Here, there is no record on '2017-09-11 00:05:00'. in that case open,close,high, low value will be set as 0(zero).
   **case b)**
   Here, there is no record on '2017-09-15 05:25:00', '2017-09-15 05:30:00' and extra but it is lie between the two record '2017-09-15 05:20:00' and 2017-09-15 08:30:00. in that case ohlc value of '2017-09-15 05:25:00' should be previous date time('2017-09-15 05:15:00') ohlc value setted.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get missing records, you need to

1. Create an extra table with all the needed values
2. `LEFT JOIN` from the extra table to the query you already have
3. Do something about the `NULLs` that will show up in the output.

If you are using MariaDB, there is a handy "sequence" generator. for step 1.  In MySQL, I recommend you pre-build a table of, say, the numbers from 0 to a million, then create the 5-minute datetimes from that using `+ INTERVAL ... SECOND`